# Anyone know this uncommon data format?

Tags: types

Has anyone ever seen this data format? I've been given a huge number of records to import from a flat file that contains number fields in some sort of packed binary format. I know from context that they represent numbers and I have some existing translations/decodings, enough to tell me a bit about how to convert. The lowest order byte represents the least significant digit and might have a sign encoded. Here is the decoded digit, then the encoded byte and corresponding bit pattern.

```
0, 0c, 0000 1100
1, 1c, 0001 1100
2, b1, 1011 0001
3, 14, 0001 0100
4, 3c, 0011 1100
5, 2a, 0010 1010
6, 25, 0010 0101
7, 40, 0100 0000
8, d0, 1101 0000
9, 91, 1001 0001
```

Bytes beyond this first one seem to pack two values, there seems to be 100 mappings from 00 to 99, I will only show a few here, first the decoded pair of digits and the hex value.

```
00, 00, 0000 0000
01, 01, 0000 0001
02, 02, 0000 0010
03, 03, 0000 0011
04, dc, 1101 1100
05, 09, 0000 1001
06, c3, 1100 0011
07, 7f, 0111 1111
08, ca, 1100 1010
09, b2, 1011 0010
10, 10, 0001 0000
11, 11, 0001 0001
12, 12, 0001 0010
13, 13, 0001 0011
14, db, 1101 1011
15, da, 1101 1010
16, 08, 0000 1000
17, c1, 1100 0001
18, 18, 0001 1000
19, 19, 0001 1001
20, c4, 1100 0100
21, b3, 1011 0011
22, c0, 1100 0000
23, d9, 1101 1001
24, bf, 1011 1111
```

If I encounter 000125 then the result is 16. 000000c90c converts to 350. If I find 000000000000000f it should convert to 0, but I don't see how, and 0000ec is supposed to result in -8.

There are enough repeating patterns here that make me suspect that it is some sort of encoding. And what I have now is enough to decode many positive numbers, but not all, and I have no idea how to handle the negative values, and I am uncertain if there is information being lost in my mapping (thinking of ieee floating point formats).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a compressed format with variable length encoding based on the frequency of the numbers?

Comment: I don't think it is compressed as the fields are fixed width and some of them are very long, 20 bytes or so. At first I thought it was Binary Coded Decimal format, or something similar, but after checking around I couldn't find anything that matched. It is from a company that automated back in the 1950s, so I bet it is some old format used to save precious bytes while retaining precision.

Comment: If you can't get an exact specification on what the data format is, how can you possibly trust what you are importing? The client/provider/source must be able to explain the format. That is, of course, unless they don't know what you are up to. Is this for law enforcement / security purposes?

Comment: Your description isn't very clear. What do the tables mean, i.e. how does 0 relate to `0c` and 1 to `1c` and so on? What do you think that data ultimately encodes: rows of numbers, text, …?

Comment: @datagod: from where I sit trust is more of a philosophical question. I am only trying to get some old data into a form where it can be accessed. I will eventually (months? years?) get something from the 'old school' source, but I like to be a bit more agile than that, thus my question.

Comment: @Gilles: These are definitely numbers and I think I provided just about all that I know about it short of listing every value I know to be correctly decoded. The first value is the decoded number and the next two are the encodings. I show the bit patterns as it helps see what is going on. I was able to reverse engineer some values based upon sample data and being able to locate other sources of the same values.

Comment: @FranK. If the values are encodings of numbers, why does `0` have a different encoding from `00` and so on?

Comment: @Gilles: The first table is for the lowest order byte and the second table is for pairs of number encoded in single bytes beyond that low order byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it uses none of the traditional mainframe formats nor any parity/error correcting schemes (count the set bits) then I can only assume that it is not something common in recent history. There might be some kind of XOR operation being applied to one of those old formats, but if so it doesn't seems to follow a pattern I can detect.

Given that nobody has seen this format or has any clue about how to write an algorithm to decode it, I'm just going to assume that it was meant to be a half-baked attempt to encrypt the numbers. If I can find the time I will write some code to analyze all 100 million values and see if I can find anything of use, but for now I'm just going to wait and see if the originators of the data can/will provide an answer. Or a clue.

I'm going to mark it answered as I don't want to torture people with an unsolvable puzzle. I'm sorry if anyone was frustrated, I was only hoping that it was something obscure that someone here might have seen before.